# Dictionary Textfile UNIX

Tags: unix, text, dictionary, text-files

Can anyone tell me where the dictionary textfile is located on UNIX systems? Or where I can get a good dictionary textfile? I have been currently using a textfile from SUN but it contains abbreviations that are not followed by a period (or else I could remove them). Could somebody point me in the right direction? I cannot seem to find anything helpful on the Mac developer dictionary tools either. I am looking for something that only contains English words, no abbreviations, and no proper nouns. It is for a word game.

Comment: Wow, I hope someday I write an equally great article on my blog so it also gets its own TLD!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `/usr/dict/words`, `/usr/share/dict/`, or `/var/lib/dict/`.

Or google "linux dictionary text" or "linux words" and find:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/dictionary-file-in-linux-652559/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)
*etc.*

Comment: When I googled that phrase, it now took me right here to your answer in stackoverflow :)